# Change the style for all the TextInputLayout (in the theme)

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

I've defined an specific TextInputLayout style, modifing the Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox

```
    <style name="TextInput" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="boxBackgroundMode">outline</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/inputBackground</item>
        <item name="boxCollapsedPaddingTop">12dp</item>
    </style>
```

Now I want to apply this style to all the TextInputLayouts. I can add the style to all the textInputLayouts, but, can I add it to my theme as the default style? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the **`textInputStyle`** attribute in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">

  <item name="textInputStyle">@style/TextInput</item>

  <!-- Default value is: <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox</item> -->
</style>
```